# Why does this NLA strip have no action, and how do I fix it?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I hardly do animation so I think these tracks were created automatically. Two tracks have a strip labelled "No Action" and I can't do anything with them. I think they are what is causing me to not be able to export the animations as part of a .glb file.

I can't seem to change them or delete them. Looking at the manual about such tracks and strips has only been confusing.

How can I format those strips properly or delete them and make new ones?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the part in the manual that concerns you
Also [here](https://3dcinetv.com/how-to-use-the-nla-in-blender/) is a link to a tutorial on the NLA

Deleting & Converting

If you decide that you no longer want a stashed action anymore, simply delete the corresponding NLA strip, then save and reload the file.

Also, note that since these are NLA strips, you can reuse these as normal NLA strips simply by un-muting (and renaming) the NLA track they live in. You may also want to move it above all the other stashed-action tracks.

Remove Empty Animation Data

This operator removes AnimData data-blocks (restricted to only those which are visible in the animation editor where it is run from) which are “empty” (i.e. that is, have no active action, drivers, and NLA tracks or strips).

It is sometimes possible to end up with a lot of data-blocks which have old and unused Animation Data containers still attached. This most commonly happens when doing motion graphics work (i.e. when some linked-in objects may have previously been used to develop a set of reusable assets), and is particularly distracting in the NLA Editor.

Comment: I gotta say, i find this confusing too. And the tutorial is old and not very good. I already looked for tutorials. An overview of NLA use is probably what i need, but i haven't found anything yet that is current and clear.

Comment: Thanks for putting this up. It's gone into my 'little black book of helpful info'  I've had little success with the NLA but plenty of hair tearing trying to figure it out!  lol. It has however increased my vocabulary!   I've developed a system of exporting Dopesheet action sections into other projects, but it's like treading a minefield when it comes to location keyframes, particularly those items parented to another.